# How to use Web.GetFileById

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, csom

I've found the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyid.aspx) on msdn and I've been struggeling to get it running. I had to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll from 16 hive (I'm using SharePoint 2013 server) inside Visual Studio to get no compile error. After running the following code, I got a "Method not found" exception:

```
    var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://myserver");

    var fileGuid = new Guid("D51C440B-4F52-4005-90BE-BDC42E850975");
    var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileById(fileGuid);

    clientContext.Load(file);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please help me on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For newcomers: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631944/how-to-use-web-getfilebyid

When you install SP SDK, two version of the client are available. 15 for SP 2010 and 16 for SP online or something like that.

Comment: 15 is for SP2013 and not for SP2010!

Comment: It depends what SDK you have, if you have SDK for SP 2010 then 15 is for SP 2010 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I do not thing you are having problem in Web.GetFileByID as I also used it in my project

```
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileById(id);
ctx.Load(file, f=>f.Name);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the CU build of your enviroment? I came to the conclusion that I might miss some updates.

Comment: It is 15.0.4737.1001(July 2015 I guess).I do not think that should be a problem

Comment: I'm using April 2015 and it's available there, so I think that's the solution. Unfortunately there is no date on the website when they added this method.

Comment: I've upgraded my VM to July 2015 CU and still can't get it running. Where are the SharePoint.Client files located you're using in your solution? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot of the errormessage here: [link](http://imgur.com/NFoDu93)