# Navigating to upload folder

Tags: development, file-upload, file, client

i need to  navigate to an 'upload' folder in the documents folder in code. I can connect to the site ok
but not sure how to navigate to that folder. I am attempting to use clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Uploads"); it does resolve but not sure if its successful as when i attempt the upload i get an authorisation exception even though earlier on i am using the same credentials to get the web title. The account i am connecting with is a site owner. I suspect i am getting the error as i am not on the folder i want to be.. not sire if there is a way of checking that?

All suggestions welcome :)

Andy

Answer (score 0):

To get into the specific folder we need to use the **"GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl"**
like below:

```
Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents");
```

**Sample upload code:**

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp13");

Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents");
string file = String.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\Files\SharePointGuidance2010.pdf");

List docLib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
ctx.Load(docLib);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file) ) )
{
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/shared documents/SubFolder/spg.pdf", stream, true);
}
```

**Example to get specific folder:**

```
   string folderName = "/MyLibrary/Upload(Folder)"; 
   Web web = context.Web;
   List docLib = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyLibrary");
   Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderName);                

   ctx.Load(context.Web);
   ctx.Load(docLib);
   ctx.Load(folder);               
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

You may refer the below thread where it has been discussed the similar question:

[Upload files to a specific folder in a Library on Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578076/upload-files-to-a-specific-folder-in-a-library-on-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks! if i have a folder 'Uploads' in my 'Documents' folder would the path be 
"/shared documents/uploads/filename.xxx'?

Comment: I don't see the folder variable being used in the logic?

Comment: Updated the answer to get the specific folder

Comment: all working, thanks a lot Habibur :)

Comment: Now.. does the context contain the guid or string for me to link to the document ?
is there a way to get that?

Comment: You are welcome mate :-) For your second query, we can get a file using the GUID and as well as the filename (string).   For getting by file name, refer the below URL example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d850f317-9ae7-4d4b-ae99-2a0ea8ac909a/get-fileref-for-filename-csom?forum=appsforsharepoint  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/get-list-of-file-names-in-sharepoint-folder

Comment: and for Get File by  ID you can refer the below example: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157378/how-to-use-web-getfilebyid

Comment: Hi - If the above answer, answered your question could you please mark this as answered, it will help the upcoming visitors, thanks for the understanding :-)

Comment: yes sure, how do i do that?